# How to prevent the same fragment open more than once in Android Architecture Navigation Components?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have an activity in which a fragment (say Fragment A) opens on click a button in activity. But When I tap this button more than one then same fragment open multiple times, overlap on each other. So how can I prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: Could you comment the code & the way that  you call the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disallow the user from opening the same fragment more than once, you have few options:

1. Disable - or remove the click listener of - the trigger when it's clicked the first time
2. Check if a fragment `isAdded()` to your activity if it's true then don't add it again

Again, from your question it's not clear what should be the logic of the fragment.